# How much can I get for selling my grandma?

Tags: cookie-clicker

Once you've played this game for a while, the cookies start rolling in so fast that it's hard to tell how many cookies you get back from selling things. **How many cookies are actually returned to you when you sell grandmas (and other production items like cursors, farms, etc.)?**

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Selling a building (grandmas are considered to be buildings) earns you 50% of the cost of buying another of that building. This is about 55% of what you paid for it.

Comment: 57.5%, to be exact. (The cost of the next building is always 15% higher.)